# How to merge 2 lists and sort them based on index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-preprocessing

I have the following dataframe:

| idx | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 12 |
| 1 | 14 | 38 |
| 2 | 11 | 88 |
| 3 | 95 | 21 |
| 4 | 19 | 98 |
| 5 | 12 | 48 |
| 6 | 35 | 38 |
| 7 | 25 | 39 |
| 8 | 65 | 28 |

I created two lists based on index say.

```
list1 = [0, 3, 6]
list2 = [5, 8]
```

I tried to write a code wherein index values from list1 takes val1 data and list2 takes val2 data and same is sorted on index.

My output list should be

```
output = [15, 95, 48, 35, 28]
```

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code, please [edit] your post and put a [mre] into it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is something like:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index()
```

Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to have a specific solution for your task

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = df.loc[df['idx'].isin(list1), 'val1']
y = df.loc[df['idx'].isin(list2), 'val2']

x = pd.concat([x, y]).sort_index().to_list()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[15, 95, 48, 35, 28]
```